# TFS POST Build Command

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, xcopy, post-build-event

I have the following post build command in a VS project:

```
if '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true' (
    xcopy /Y /R /C "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)common\bin"
)
```

The problem that I have is that the project is referenced from two separate solutions (meaning that for one it is not valid).  My impression was that this should work anyway, because of the `/C` but that seems to not be the case.

My question is: what are the possibilities for getting around this?  Basically, I just want this to work when it works and do nothing when it doesn't.

Comment: Why doesn't it work for both solutions?  Are you getting an error? whats the error message?

Comment: Because the $(SolutionDir) differs

Comment: Right, but your using the MSBuild property, so it should copy your files to both solutions dirs.  Does this fail for some reason?

Comment: Yes, the destination directory doesn't exist in one of the solutions

Answer (score 0):

If $(SolutionDir) does not work for you, your have to use a path relative to $(ProjectDir), like $(ProjectDir)....\common.
Another alternative is an environment variable that must be set on a per-machine basis.